# How can I call a method for a derived class?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, radix, derived-class

### In Short

I want to be able to call a method, the method takes a parameter of type `ObservableCollection<Base>` but I want to call it with `ObservableCollection<Derived>`. It says it cannot convert between the two.

### Longer

I want to call a WPF Window, in it is a ListBox that will bind to an `ObservableCollection`. I want the window to display some basic information that are common to two different classes. The classes are `Derived1` and `Derived2`, and are based an `BaseClass`. I am able to call the method had the type just been `BaseClass`, but I want to pass a list through.

So I have two collections :

```
ObservableCollection<Derived1> A;
ObservableCollection<Derived2> B;
```

And want to be able to call a method like the one below, with the above two collections so I don't need to duplicate code.

```
public void InitialiseWindow(ref ObservableCollection<BaseClass> List)
{
    this.List=List;
}
```

But it throws an error:

```
cannot convert from 'ref System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Derived1>' to 'ref System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Base>'
```

### Whilst I'm here

Would there be a better way of binding the Collection so changed made in the `Window` will reflect on the source, instead of using `ref`?

### Solution

I modified the constructor for the `Window` so that it casts the `IEnumerable` to a public member of type `ObservableCollection`. Since the window would only be shown modally, this the member could be accessed after the window closes.

```
public ObservableCollection<BaseClass> List;

public InitialiseWindow(IEnumerable<BaseClass> List)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.List=new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>(List);
}
```

Comment: +1 - good question with carefully selected details. For future - don't add "thank you notes" (upvote/accept instead) and signature (edit your user name instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're exposing it purely for binding purposes, it's sufficient to pass an `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` reference.  The data binding system will automatically inspect the actual instance to see if it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so it does not need the bound property to be typed explicitly as an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Thanks, but will it be possible to modify the collection? In other words add and remove items.

Comment: @Brownish, if you need to modify the collection (so it's not just being used for binding) one option is to supply an interface or callbacks to perform the necessary modifications.  The tricky thing here, though, is that now the consuming class needs to know to only add derived instances, so you may want to think about how this is exposed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I modified the code as shown in the edit above. I feel like it might not be the best solution, but perhaps the easiest. I also think I'll look into callbacks and interfaces so I can understand them, then maybe implement them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Types are different and for `ref` types must match exactly.

There are cases when you can use derived class in similar way - read on [co-variance/contra-variance for C# templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I.e. you can do

```
IEnumerable<Object> objects = new List<String>();
```

because IEnumerable defines it argument as [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

```
 public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```